# Use object defined to another object in select new Entity Framework ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I wrote a query and i filled my list object using that query.

My problem is that i need use that object to fill another object.

I can not duplicate the statement that used to fill in the first object because it is too heavy.

So i want use the final data that is in object 1. Here is a simple example that i need:

```
var query= _DB.table1.include("table2")
.select(x=> new
  {
  object1= expression1,
  object2= object1 +expression2
  {
```

Just remember that i can not copy "expression1" in object2. How could I go about this?

Comment: did you try join query for example: (from tbl1 in _DB.table1 join tbl2 _DB.table2 on tbl11.Id equal tbl2.tbl1Id select new { object1 = tbl1.column, object2 = tbl2.column })

Comment: i used but i want another thing that you mention... i want use data in object1 to expresseion2 that fill object2

Comment: can you want to do sub select?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: sub select is used for separate query... but i need object data from same query.